# Transferring JSON Data into an array using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

This is my JSON code

```
{
"jobs": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Software Developer",
  "applicants": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Rich Hickey",
      "tags": ["clojure", "java", "immutability", "datomic", "transducers"]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Guido van Rossum",
      "tags": ["python", "google", "bdfl", "drop-box"]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Software Architect",
  "applicants": [
    {
      "id": 42,
      "name": "Rob Pike",
      "tags": ["plan-9", "TUPE", "go", "google", "sawzall"]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Guido van Rossum",
      "tags": ["python", "google", "bdfl", "drop-box"]
    },
    {
      "id": 1337,
      "name": "Jeffrey Dean",
      "tags": ["spanner", "BigTable", "MapReduce", "deep learning", "massive clusters"]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I want to put the list of "Jobs" in an array using ruby. 
I have the following code so far.

```
require 'json'
file = File.read(filepath)
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

How do I iterate on the data_hash and chose what information I want and place it in an array?

Comment: Use `Hash#each` method to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#each` because `data_hash['jobs']` contains an array of jobs:

`data_hash['jobs'].each {|job| ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
arr = Array.new
data_hash.each { |job| 
arr.insert(job['name'])
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when I use this.

No implicit conversion of string to integer

Comment: Ummm try this, `arr.insert("#{job['name']}")`

Answer (score 0):

use `Array#map` for shorter code

```
data_hash['jobs'].map do |job| 
   # Do whatever you want with the job here
   properties = %w(title applicants)
   job.select{ |key| properties.include?(key) }
end
```